# How to take only articles by given user Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to display in my user/myarticlesview only articles by logged in user.
How can i do that:
Here is my User model and Article schema:

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    passwordHash: {type: String, required: true},
    salt: {type: String, required: true},
    articles: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Article'}],
    roles: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Role'}]
}
```

);

```
let articleSchema = mongoose.Schema (
{
    author: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    title: {type: String, required: true },
    content: {type: String, required: true },
    phone: {type: Number, required: true },
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now() }
}
```

);

I want to do this in my userController and passed it to the view:

```
myArticlesGet: (req, res) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
    }

    res.render('user/myarticles')

}
```

I cant figure it out how to make the query.Thank you.

Comment: are you using [express sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session)?

Comment: Yes i am usting express sessions

Comment: From session, find out the user document. Once you get the user document, you just have to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) `articles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `express sessions` you can store `userId` in the express session when the user is authenticated and then you can get user articles from user like that

```
User.find({_id: req.session.userId}).populate('articles')
```